# Positioning a table within jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery verical tabs and incorporating tables as the data shown when a tab is clicked. The problem is that my tables show on the bottom of the tabs as oppose to floating on the right hand side of the tabs like I want.
I have tried recreating my problem [JS-FIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qTXnN/41/) and if you click on the trash tab you will see a table on the bottom of the tabs... the only difference is that in my script the anchor tags are external php files that contain tables. I've tried `style="float:right"` & it did not work, I am unsure if  jquery tabs is conflicting what I'm trying to do, but would like to know. I am at my wits end trying to figure out how to get the tables to position correctly. I would very much appreciate any assistance or tips regardless of what on that one may have for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computed style of the tab is `~827.966px` and you table width is `940px`.
That's why it goes down.
Remove your table width or change to a lower value.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qTXnN/46/)

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the width of your table to 920 pixels. Try to make it narrower.

If you have to make it 920px wide, then try to add `display: table` style to your `div`
See [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanleywym/7Cx3s/)

Answer (score 0):

its because you have the width of the table set so wide that it will not fit

```
<table width="920" style="background-color:#F2F2F2;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

you have to change the width of the parent , or change the overflow